# Opaque text over semi-transparent background

Tags: html, css, tumblr-themes

I am a total newbie to code and I am trying to edit one of tumblr themes.
I have been ravaging the web for tutorials but I can't solve this.
I want to have a transparent content background, which I have so far, by adding opacity: `#background { background:{color:Content Background}; margin: 0 auto; width: 730px; **opacity: 0.5;** }` but I would like the text to remain opaque. How can I do this, please?

Here is what I have:

```css
 body {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: {
     color: Background
   }
   url('{image:Background}');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:center;
   background-attachment:fixed;
   color: {
     color: Primary colour
   }
   ;
   font-family: {
     font: Body
   }
   ,
   Baskerville,
   Times,
   "Times New Roman",
   serif;
   font-weight:300;
   font-size:13px;
   line-height:24px;
 }
 #background {
   background: {
     color: Content Background
   }
   ;
   margin:0 auto;
   width:730px;
   opacity:0.5;
 }
 #background-inner {
   margin: 0 auto;
   background: {
     color: Content Background
   }
   ;
   border-left:15px solid;
   {
     color: Stripe
   }
   ;
   border-right:15px solid {
     color: Stripe
   }
   ;
   width:670px;
 }
 section#blog {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 670px;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First of all your CSS has a few errors.
- Secondly, in order to achieve what you want you need to use [RGBA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) in `background`.

Why you need to use `rgba`?

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)

> The value applies to the element as a whole, including its contents,
>   even though the value is not inherited by child elements. Thus, an
>   element and its contained children all have the same opacity relative
>   to the element's background, even if the element and its children have
>   different opacities relative to one another.

#### Snippet

```css
body {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) /* background black with 50% opacity */
}
```

```html
<div>This will be opaque</div>
```

Comment: To explain a bit more the concept: Setting opacity on a parent element will affects all child elements and anything within that element too, and can't be over ridden on child elements. Whereas rgba affects only one aspect, which is the color.

Comment: Added a detailed explanation (I couldn't remembered where I have seen this text before) :)

Comment: Your explanation was incredibly useful! Thank you!